# how to Connect Oppo devices to Android Studio over MacBook Pro?

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, adb, oppo

**Environment Specs:** MacBook Pro, MacOs Mojava 10.14.16

**Phone:** Oppo Reno2 f, Android Version 9

**Connecting steps;**

- Enabled Developer options
- Enabled USB Debugging
- Enabled USB configuration PTP

**Notes**

- Same phone connects over windows machines successfully with either MTP or PTP USB configurations
- Other brands like Samsung, HTC and Huawei connects seamlessly on The Mac environment

The question is; how can I create a successful/stable connection over the ADB?, and why is this happening with this compination Oppo/Mac?

Comment: Choose "Connect as MIDI" option

Comment: @mayur, didn't work

Comment: Go to settings and explicitly choose MIDI option.. or if you get a pop up asking on how to use the device on your phone.. choose MIDI.. the android studio should be able to recognise.. works well with my MacBook Pro

Answer (score 2):

For me after enabling Developer Option,USB debugger and default USB configuration as MTP it worked and working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

"USB configuration" RNDIS (USB Ethernet) will allow you to connect.

Comment: didn't work either, the ADB reads the device for less than a second then disconnects

Comment: RNDIS (USB Ethernet)  works on my oppo A54 and Win11 Xiaomi Book, will update if it would work on my Mac Mini